# Order and trim an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

This code outputs the arrays below

```
$upcoming =  $event_date[0]['event_dates'];
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_date] => 2020-02-20 00:00:00
            [event_start_time] => 09:14:00
            [event_end_time] => 13:14:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_date] => 2020-02-15 00:00:00
            [event_start_time] => 09:15:00
            [event_end_time] => 11:15:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event_date] => 2020-02-26 00:00:00
            [event_start_time] => 14:15:00
            [event_end_time] => 18:15:00
        )

)
```

I've managed to isolate just the `[event_date]` value using this:

```
$event_dates = array_column($upcoming, 'event_date');
```

This outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2020-02-20 00:00:00
    [1] => 2020-02-15 00:00:00
    [2] => 2020-02-26 00:00:00
)
```

I can output the first key like this

```
 $date = $event_dates[0];
```

I'd need to do a couple of other things:

- Sort the `array` by date. `2020-02-15 00:00:00` should be at the top of the list.
- Check if `event_date` exists.

I'd really like to see how this works, so if we could create a variable for each step that'd help me understand it better.

Many thanks.

Comment: asort($event_dates); will output '2020-02-15 00:00:00' for first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
$dates = [
    [
        'event_date' => '2020-02-20 00:00:00',
        'event_start_timet_date' => '09:14:00',
        'event_end_time' => '13:14:00',
    ],
    [
        'event_date' => '2020-02-15 00:00:00',
        'event_start_timet_date' => '09:15:00',
        'event_end_time' => '11:15:00',
    ],
    [
        'event_date' => '2020-02-26 00:00:00',
        'event_start_timet_date' => '14:15:00',
        'event_end_time' => '18:15:00',
    ],
];

usort($dates, function(array $a, array $b) {
    if (!isset($a['event_date']) || !isset($b['event_date'])) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a['event_date'] <=> $b['event_date'];
});
```

Or, if you know that 'event_date' will be presence in that array (and you have PHP 7.4), you might like to try this one

```
usort($dates, fn(array $a, array $b): int => $a['event_date'] <=> $b['event_date']);
```

Comment: That's excellent! Is there a way to add `isset` to this: `$event_dates = array_column($upcoming, 'event_date');` 

When `event_date` isn't available this part of the code throws an error: `array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Comment: well, in that case, take a look the example #4 from the docu: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php
But I think the easiest way it would be to use `isset` in `usort` function.

Comment: I've tweaked the code, not using `array_column`. Is there a way to use `isset` with the first value of `usort`? When there's no values in `$dates` I get this error: `usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Comment: What do you mean by that? I don't understand that question. `usort()` expect an array. If you pass a null then you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks, I've wrapped the code in `isset` to check if  `event_dates` exists. In this instance it would be rare `event_dates` wouldn't be available - but I like to have a backup just incase! Thanks for you your help!